# Get name of an option

Tags: c#, excel

I want my C# to return the text that is displayed on Excel's own GUI, both menus and options.  For example with the tick box called "Trust Access to the VBA project object model." I want to be able to read that text.  Or with the "File" menu, I want to be able to return the text "File"

If the user has their machine set up in another language I want to be able to read the text that is displayed in their language.  So if I ask for the name of the "File" menu and their machine is speaking German then it's going to be the German word for File and not the English word.

I don't want to care what language setting people have set up, I just want to return the text that they see, so that I can direct the user to the correct options.

Comment: You might want to look at pInvoking EnumWindows. See the second example: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.enumwindows  This isn't going to be terribly straight-forward. You'll need to use Spy++ to find the classes and such of indivudal UI controls you're looking for and then use EnumWindows to locate the HWNDS and then pInvoke GetWindowText (http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowText.html) to retrieve the text from the various contrls.